# How can I find the cause of unwanted vibration in Neovim in Termius?

Tags: neovim, debugging

I am using Neovim in Termius on iPhone.

Before today it was working fine.

Today it began executing a vibrate on my phone for every command: `nvim` - `i` - `ESC` - `:q`.

There are no unwanted vibrates in Vim or in my shell in general.

Being new to Neovim, the only things I have changed were tinkering with the `init.vim` file and a few plug-ins with `/local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim`, but I deleted those files and still get the vibration.

I tried to see what command is being triggered with `nvim -V9nvim.log`, but after commands that vibrated, no error or command is shown:

```
-- INSERT --


Writing ShaDa file "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada"
chdir(/home/ubuntu)
chdir(/usr/share/nvim/runtime/doc)
chdir(/home/ubuntu)
chdir(/home/ubuntu)
chdir(/usr/share/nvim/runtime/doc)
```

I have also tried setting options regarding bells off, such as `:set bellsoff=all`, which has had no effect.

I just did `sudo apt-get purge neovim` and reinstalled it and it still vibrates, so I don’t know if this is a config or dependency I missed or if the error is in the relationship between my terminal and Neovim.

**How can I log Neovim’s execution completely so that I can see what command is triggering the vibration?**

Comment: Have you tried looking at `:messages`  (command line). I don't think vim is well suited to a touch-interface, if that's what you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried various commands to print current error messages. Perhaps this is a bug. However, the question is actually how to see the lowest possible level stack trace. I want to see completely what Vim is doing, see it call what it’s calling.

Comment: Try `:set verbose=5`